# Spark Streaming: Inputs are received but not processed

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a simple SparkStreaming application, that consists in sending messages through a socket server to the SparkStreaming Context and printing them.
This is my code, which I am running in IntelliJ IDE:

```
    SparkConf sparkConfiguration= new SparkConf().setAppName("DataAnalysis").setMaster("spark://IP:7077");
    JavaStreamingContext sparkStrContext=new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConfiguration, Durations.seconds(1));
    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> receiveData=sparkStrContext.socketTextStream("localhost",5554);
```

I am running this application in a standalone cluster mode, with one worker (an Ubuntu VM) and a master (my Windows host).
This is the problem: When I run the application, I see that it successfully connected to the master, but it doesn't print any lines:

[image]

it just stays this way permanently.
If I go to the Spark UI, I find that the SparkStreaming Context is receiving inputs, but they are not being processed:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me please? Thank you so much.

Comment: how are you launching your application ? client mode or cluster mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform below.

```
sparkStrContext.start();              // Start the computation
sparkStrContext.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

Once you do this , you need to post the messages at port 5554 , for this you will first need to run Netcat (a small utility found in most Unix-like systems) as a data server by using and start pushing the stream.

For example , you need to do like below.

## TERMINAL 1:

```
# Running Netcat

$ nc -lk 5554

hello world
```

## TERMINAL 2: RUNNING Your streaming program

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1357008430000 ms
-------------------------------------------
hello world
...



    ...
```

You can check similar example [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java)

Comment: thank you, but I have started the spark streaming context, just chose not to write it because I thought it was obvious. It's not my first spark project.

Comment: Which mode you are running ?

Comment: I'm running in cluster mode. In local mode everything works well, but not in cluster mode

Comment: Should I submit the application in a different way? I'm just running the application in the IDE, maybe I need to create a jar file or something like that...

Comment: use spark-sumbit and pass your jar , you need to pass your spark master as well ,check this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit